# VisualStudio 2010 : A way to have proposals diplayed without leaving the keyboard?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, smart-tags

Is there a way to go from this state :

[image]

To this one :

[image]

without leaving the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut to expand smart tags in Visual Studio is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (period).